# Asp.net MVC Azure Cloud Role - Precompile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

We are seeing an issue with pages taking a while to load on first run (per user session), we believe this is because the views are not pre-compiled but we cant find any documentation on how to precompile the views when deploying to Azure using Visual Studios Publish Azure application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, what you are experiencing is what is called a "cold start", this is what happens when an application first starts (after a new deployment) or after being idle for a long period.

Assuming you are using Azure App Service (Web Apps) to deploy your application, to avoid dealing with this "cold start" problem, there are two things you should do:

1. Deploy the new code to a staging slot, instead of replacing the old code with new one in production. See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots).
2. Enable `Always On` in the `Application settings` for your Web App. This will keep your application from stopping due to inactivity.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am looking for a way to avoid the "cold start" altogether, is there a way to force each page to open \ run on deploy?

Comment: You don't need to do it for every page, just hit one page and that will start the app.